# pythonのwebスクレイピングについて

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping

こんにちは　最近pythonを学び始めた初心者です、質問をさせていただきます。
ヤフーニュースから記事のタイトルだけを抜き出すコードを描いたのですが、
    bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you 
    requested: html_parser. Do you need to install a parser library?
と表示されてしまいます。インタラクティブモードで実行したときはうまく表示されたのですが...
どのようにすれば解決できますか？

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = requests.get('https://news.yahoo.co.jp/list/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text,'html_parser')
midashi_all = soup.find_all('dl', class_='title')
for midashi in midashi_all:
    print(midashi.dt.get_text())
```

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoupに指定しているパーサが間違っているようです。`html_parser` ではなく、 `html.parser` を指定してみてください。

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = requests.get('https://news.yahoo.co.jp/list/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text,'html.parser')
midashi_all = soup.find_all('dl', class_='title')
for midashi in midashi_all:
    print(midashi.dt.get_text())
```